# public websites on different ports not working, iis 7

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have my default website running on port 80, running perfectly fine. When I add a new website on port 3000, I can view it at localhost:3000 no problem. However, when on a rogue computer visiting domain.com:3000, nothing. Any ideas?

EDIT/

Even when on local network viewing servername:3000, nothing shows. Only localhost:3000 on the physical computer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you opened the new port in your firewall?